# what anti-ddos security systems python use for socket TCP connections?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ddos, python-sockets

More in detail, would like to know:

- what is the default SYN_RECEIVED timer,
- how do i get to change it,
- are SYN cookies or SYN caches implemented.

I'm about to create a simple special-purpose publically accessible server. i must choose whether using built-in TCP sockets or RAW sockets and re-implement the TCP handshake if these security mechanisms are not present.

Comment: The Python runtime has nothing to do with any of these decisions. This entirely and unequivocally depends on which operating system you're running on and how it's configured.

Comment: Also, frankly, trying to put DDOS protections at the application layer at all is Doing It Wrong. There's a reason load-balancing &c. is done in a separate layer. Take advantage.

Comment: ...Python, and especially the default CPython runtime, is a poorly-chosen tool for the kinds of things that a good HA layer should do -- it doesn't do concurrency nearly as well as something written in Go or (very carefully written) native C can, and the runtime isn't in a position to take advantage of new and modern kernel features soon after they appear. Write your application layer in a language that makes sense for its job -- and use frontend web and load-balancing layers written in languages that makes sense for *their* jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe are internals of the TCP stack of the operating system. Python just uses this stack via the socket interface. I doubt that any of these settings can be changed specific to the application at all, i.e. these are system wide settings which can only be changed with administrator privileges.